How to save an image in mongodb
I want to upload and save an image from my client to my mongodb using nodejs and express but I do get a wrong response. If my approach is incorrect please point in the right direction.
Below is the code I have tried from the html form down to my server side code then to my schema.
My HTML code below:
<form action="/addWine" method="post">
                <label for="">Name:</label>
                <textarea name="goods" id="" cols="10" rows="5"></textarea>

                <label for="">Quantity:</label>
                <input type="text" name="quantity">

                <label for="">Price:</label>
                <input type="text" name="price">

                <label for="">Photo:</label>
                <input type="file" name="photo">

                <button type="submit">ADD WINE</button>
            </form>

My server side code below:
const express = require('express')
const {default:mongoose} = require('mongoose')
const multer = require('multer')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const upload = multer({ dest: './uploads'})
const Wine = require('./model/wine')
app.post('/addWine', upload.single('photo'), async (req, res)=>{
    try {
        const {goods, price, quantity} = req.body
        const filePath = req.body.file.buffer;
        const wine = new Wine ({
            goods:goods,
            price:price,
            quantity:quantity,
            photo:filePath
        })
        await wine.save()
        res.redirect('/admin')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.redirect('/addWine')
    }
})


This is my schema:
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const wineSchema = new Schema(
    {
        goods:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        quantity:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        price:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        photo:{
            type:Buffer,
            contentType:String,
            required:true
        },
    }
)
module.exports = mongoose.model('Wine', wineSchema)

This is the error messages I receive:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'b
uffer')


it's req.file.buffer, not req.body.file.buffer, see: File information

Issue you're facing is caused by trying to access the file's buffer incorrectly. In Multer, uploaded files are stored in req.file, not in req.body.
Server-side Code
app.post('/addWine', upload.single('photo'), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { goods, price, quantity } = req.body;
        
        // Access the uploaded file's buffer and MIME type from `req.file`
        const photoBuffer = req.file.buffer; 
        const contentType = req.file.mimetype;

        // Create a new wine document with the file buffer and contentType
        const wine = new Wine({
            goods: goods,
            price: price,
            quantity: quantity,
            photo: {
                data: photoBuffer, 
                contentType: contentType
            }
        });

        await wine.save();
        res.redirect('/admin');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.redirect('/addWine');
    }
});

Mongoose Schema
const wineSchema = new Schema({
    goods: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    quantity: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    photo: {
        data: Buffer, // Store the file buffer here
        contentType: String, // Store the MIME type here
        required: true
    }
});

Your HTML form includes the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute, which is required for file uploads.
<form action="/addWine" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

In Multer, the uploaded file is available in req.file. The file’s binary data (buffer) is stored in req.file.buffer, and its MIME type (e.g., image/png) is available in req.file.mimetype. Make sure to save both the buffer and MIME type in MongoDB.
Let me know if you'd like to anything else!

Serve Image (read)
When the image is requested, you can retrieve the image buffer from MongoDB and send it back with the correct content type.
app.get('/wine/photo/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const wine = await Wine.findById(req.params.id);

        if (!wine || !wine.photo) {
            return res.status(404).send('Image not found');
        }

        // Set the correct content type and send the image buffer
        res.set('Content-Type', wine.photo.contentType);
        res.send(wine.photo.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send('Error retrieving image');
    }
});

Display the Image
<img id="winePhoto" src="/wine/photo/{{wineId}}" alt="Wine Photo">

You can also fetch the image dynamically in your JavaScript code
const wineId = 'your_wine_id_here'; // Replace with actual wine ID

// Fetch the image and display it in the <img> element
document.getElementById('winePhoto').src = `/wine/photo/${wineId}`;


Thanks buddy,  I have tried it and it worked. How do I read them from my client

@Francis, please check—I’ve updated my answer.
